# Waiting for the previous function to be completed in Python

Tags: python, function, wait, scp

is there any solution in python which lets a function execute after the previous one was finished?

Here is one of the ideas I'm using now. But it is not solving the problem when files are larger and the program needs more time.

```py
def copy_to_jumphost(self):
        try:
            if self.connect():
                stdin, stdout, stderr = self.client.exec_command('sshpass -p %s scp -r %s@%s:%s/' % (self.password,self.username,self.hostname,self.log_path) + self.lista[self.file_number].rstrip() + ' ' + '/home/%s/' % (self.username) + self.lista[self.file_number].rstrip())   
        except (AttributeError, TypeError) as e:
            print("Error occurred:", e)
```

```py
try:
    if self.connect():
        if self.copy_to_jumphost():
            ftp_client = self.client.open_sftp()
            ftp_client.get(filepath, self.localpath)
            print("Success! \nFile coppied to %s" %(self.localpath))
        else: 
            time.sleep(5)
            ftp_client = self.client.open_sftp()
            ftp_client.get(filepath, self.localpath)
            print("Success but needed some time! \nFile coppied to %s" %(self.localpath))
except (AttributeError, TypeError) as e:
    print("Error occurred:", e)
```

Perfect situation for me will be if in else statement there is a solution to wait for finishing the `copy_to_jumphost()` function, because `time.sleep(5)` will fail if I will need to copy larger files.

Comment: your `copy_to_jumphost(self)` does not return anything so the code following `if self.copy_to_jumphost():`  will never get executed

Comment: so it means usage ```if self.copy_to_jumphost():``` was unnecessary right?

Comment: it just does not return anything. I did not understand what function you want to wait before the execution of the next. if you mean the code after `if self.copy_to_jumphost():` condition, then definitely once you fix the above problem the code in `else` clause will be executed after the `if` clause.

Comment: @eugen: I believe the OP wants the `copy_to_jumphost()` function to wait until the command executed by `self.client.exec_command()` finishes.

Comment: I still do not understand how `copy_to_jumphost()` can waite another call which is inside itself. Maybe there is something else that I am missing...

Comment: @martineau yes, that is correct. I added ```return True``` to the ```try``` statement inside copy_to_jumphost() function. Now statement ```if self.copy_to_jumphost():``` is correct?

Comment: That will not tell you if the `sshpass` command is finished — only that `self.client.exec_command()` executed..